# Web Audio API: offset/seek to a certain point in a buffer/wav file

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Is it possible play an audio file at a certain point in the clip? For example, if the file is 8 seconds long, I'd like it to start at second 4.

Answer (score 1):

If you've loaded it as an AudioBuffer, sure - just set the offset in the start() call.